# warning: implicit declaration of function 'getline'

Tags: c, project

Hi I'm almost done with a project I have for class. I need to sort the priority of people in an airline based on a few factors. This is my project description:

"An airline company uses the formula shown below to determine the priority of passengers on the
waiting list for overbooked flights.
Priority Number = (A / 1000) + B - C
where
A is the customer’s total mileage in the past year
B is the number of years in his or her frequent flier program
C is a sequence number representing the customer’s arrival position when he or she booked the
flight.
Given a file of overbooked customers as shown in the table below, write a program that reads the
file and determines each customer’s priority number. The program then builds a priority queue
using the priority number and prints a list of waiting customers in priority sequence."

I feel my code encompasses the main idea, but I am having issues with getline. When I compile the code (shown below) it gives me an error:
"|24|warning: implicit declaration of function 'getline' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|"

Please help me fix this so it will compile. I've tried a lot of things and nothing works.

Here is the code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * fp; //create file pointer to be read later
    char * line = NULL;
    int temp,count=0,len=0,mileage[100],read,years[100],sequence[100],priority[100];
    char name[100][100],tempst[100];
    fp = fopen("customers.txt", "r"); //opening the file

    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    int i;



    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) { //start reading file and recording data
        i=0;

        while(line[i]!=' ' || (line[i+1]>='A' && line[i+1]<='z'))
        {
            name[count][i]=line[i];
            i++;
        }
        name[count][i++]='\0';
        mileage[count]=0;

        while(line[i]!=' ')
        {
            mileage[count]=mileage[count]*10+(line[i]-'0');
            i++;
        }
        i++;
        years[count]=0;

        while(line[i]!=' ')
        {
            years[count]=years[count]*10+(line[i]-'0');
            i++;
        }
        i++;
        sequence[count]=0;

        while(line[i]!='\0')
        {
            sequence[count]=sequence[count]*10+(line[i]-'0');
            i++;
        }
        priority[count]=(mileage[count]/1000)+years[count]-sequence[count];
        count++;

    }

    for( i=0;i<count-1;i++) // calculate priority
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<count;j++)
        {
            if(priority[i]<priority[j])
            {
                temp=priority[i];
                priority[i]=priority[j];
                priority[j]=temp;
                strcpy(tempst,name[i]);
                strcpy(name[i],name[j]);
                strcpy(name[j],tempst);
            }
        }
    }

    for( i=0;i<count;i++) //print priority
    {
        printf("%s %d\n",name[i],priority[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `line` is incorrectly passed. See here on how to properly use `getline`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/FILE/
Also, why is `len=0`?

Comment: @Everyone Passing `&line` where `line == (char*)0` along with `&(size_t){0}` is a supported use of the `getline` POSIX function: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html .

Comment: @PSkocik my bad. Didn't know POSIX supports this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
```

or

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
```

should get you `getline` on GNU systems, but there might be another way to enable it on a different POSIX system.

After enabling `getline` like that, the `len` variable should be typed `size_t`, not `int` so that `&len` is correctly typed as `size_t *`.

It is possible that your project testing software doesn't support the `getline` POSIX function in which case you might need to rethink your design in terms of standard C functions instead.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and still get the same error.. implicit declaration. undefined reference to getline. I do not understand what is causing this. I tried it on a few online C compilers and they compile without this error. I'm working on Codeblocks with MingGW compiler.

Comment: ```

int main()
{
    FILE * fp; //create file pointer to be read later
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t * len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    int temp,count=0,mileage[100],years[100],sequence[100],priority[100];
    char name[100][100],tempst[100];
    fp = fopen("customers.txt", "r"); //opening the file

    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    int i;



    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) { //start reading file and recording data
        i=0;
....
```

Comment: @CoderJoe `MinGW` doesn't support POSIX. It's possible your school's testing environment doesn't either.

Comment: @CoderJoe - if you don't have `getline()`, then use `fgets()` and a fixed buffer of sufficient size to hold the line. (e.g. `char line[1024];` will do -- don't skimp on buffer size -- reduce as appropriate to 2X longest line if on a microcontroller like a TI MSP432)

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to fix this bug is to use `fget` instead of `getline`.
To replace getline with fgets in the given code, you'll need to allocate a buffer for fgets to read into and then parse the line manually. The fgets function reads a line from the specified stream up to a specified number of characters or until a newline character is encountered. Here's how can modify the code to use fgets:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp; // Create file pointer to be read later
    char line[256]; // Buffer to hold each line read from the file
    int temp, count = 0, mileage[100], years[100], sequence[100], priority[100];
    char name[100][100], tempst[100];
    fp = fopen("customers.txt", "r"); // Opening the file

    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    int i;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) { // Start reading file and recording data
        i = 0;
        // Remove newline character if present
        size_t len = strlen(line);
        if (len > 0 && line[len - 1] == '\n') {
            line[len - 1] = '\0';
        }

        // Parsing logic
        while (line[i] != ' ' || (line[i + 1] >= 'A' && line[i + 1] <= 'z')) {
            name[count][i] = line[i];
            i++;
        }
        name[count][i++] = '\0';
        mileage[count] = 0;

        while (line[i] != ' ') {
            mileage[count] = mileage[count] * 10 + (line[i] - '0');
            i++;
        }
        i++;
        years[count] = 0;

        while (line[i] != ' ') {
            years[count] = years[count] * 10 + (line[i] - '0');
            i++;
        }
        i++;
        sequence[count] = 0;

        while (line[i] != '\0') {
            sequence[count] = sequence[count] * 10 + (line[i] - '0');
            i++;
        }
        priority[count] = (mileage[count] / 1000) + years[count] - sequence[count];
        count++;
    }

    // Sorting logic
    for (i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++) {
            if (priority[i] < priority[j]) {
                temp = priority[i];
                priority[i] = priority[j];
                priority[j] = temp;
                strcpy(tempst, name[i]);
                strcpy(name[i], name[j]);
                strcpy(name[j], tempst);
            }
        }
    }

    // Printing logic
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s %d\n", name[i], priority[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp); // Close the file when done
    return 0;
}
```

In this modified code, I've added a buffer line with a fixed size of 256 characters. This should be sufficient for most lines, but if you expect lines to be longer, you can increase the buffer size accordingly.

Please note that the parsing logic inside the loop may need to be adjusted if it relies on the behavior of getline. The fgets function reads a fixed number of characters, so if the line is longer than the buffer, it will only read a portion of the line. Additionally, fgets includes the newline character in the buffer, which is why I've added code to remove it.

Finally, I've added fclose(fp); at the end of the program to properly close the file once we're done with it. This is good practice and helps prevent resource leaks.