# Implicit declaration of getline in C

Tags: c, io

I have recently started learning I/O. But my compiler is not executing this code. It is showing **Implicit declaration of function *getline***. Can someone plz tell me how I can fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()

{
    size_t size = 10;
    char *string;
    string = (char *)malloc(size);
    getline(&string, &size, stdin);
    puts("You entered the following string: ");
    puts(string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [warning: implicit declaration of function 'getline'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59014090/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function-getline)

Comment: Tip for next time: Web search is your friend. Posters are expected to do research first and it is often faster to find the info with a quick search than posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

`getline` is not a standard function of c language and is not available on windows.

If you're on linux then try checking [warning: implicit declaration of function 'getline'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59014090/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function-getline) out.

I suggest you use `fgets` for alternative.

Comment: But this code is working on my other PC, which has also windows on it.  So I don't think this error is due to OS.

Comment: @PiyushJaswal That's strange... I'd say showing error is normal and working on Windows is weird behaviour.