# Implicit declaration of function 'getline'

Tags: c, file-handling, getline

/*File Copy: Write a C program to copy a file using file operations*/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
    FILE* fin, *fout;
    fin = fopen("text.txt","r");
    fout = fopen("write.txt","w+");
    if(NULL == fin) {
        printf("FILE not found!\n");
    }
    else {
        size_t maxlen = 100;
        char* ptr = (char*)calloc(maxlen, sizeof(char));
        // ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
        while(getline(&ptr,&maxlen,fin) != -1) {
            fprintf(fout,"%s",ptr);
        }
        free(ptr);
    }
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using `getline()` function in vscode compiler but its giving error as mentioned here -

> warning: implicit declaration of function 'getline'
> [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]    20 |
> while(getline(&ptr,&maxlen,fin) != -1){

Comment: What OS?  What compiler?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59014090/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function-getline  This **may** be a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Have a look at this https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline

Comment: I am using windows os and visual studio code

Answer (score 3):

`getline()` is not part of the standard C library.

When compiling and adhering to the C standard, a warning like "implicit declaration of function 'getline'" is expected as the function lacks a prototype.

Either:

- Do not use `getline()`.  1) Re-code with standard C library I/O or 2) write your own `getline()`.  `getline()` source code is not hard to find.
- Enable compiler options to use that extended function, if it exists.  (I do not expect *visual studio code* to have it.)

---

With common `getline()`, no need to pre-allocate

```
        // size_t maxlen = 100;
        // char* ptr = (char*)calloc(maxlen, sizeof(char));
        size_t maxlen = 0;
        char* ptr = NULL;
        while(getline(&ptr,&maxlen,fin) != -1) {
            fprintf(fout,"%s",ptr);
        }
```

---

As OP's goal is *Write a C program to copy a file using file operations*, a better approach would open files in *binary* mode and use `fread()/fwrite()`.  The `getline()/fprintf()` approach assumes a file lacking embedded *null characters*, predicable line endings, and other *text* attributes.

```
// Sample unchecked code

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  const char *ifilename = "text.txt";
  FILE *fin = fopen(ifilename, "rb");
  if (fin == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open \"%s\" for reading.\n", ifilename);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  const char *ofilename = "write.txt";
  FILE *fout = fopen(ofilename, "wb");
  if (fout == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open \"%s\" for writing.\n", ofilename);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  unsigned char buf[BUFSIZ];
  size_t n_read;
  while ((n_read = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZ, fin)) > 0) {
    size_t n_written = fwrite(buf, 1, n_read, fout);
    if (n_written != n_read) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed writing to \"%s\".\n", ofilename);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }
  
  fclose(fout);
  if (ferror(fin)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed reading from \"%s\".n", ifilename);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  fclose(fin);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```